# -[__NSCFConstantString ascending]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15

Tags: ios

I am getting a strange error. When I am trying to sort an array..

```
- (NSArray *)sortItemsUsingDescriptor:(NSSortDescriptor *)descriptor
{

        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];

//This line is where the exception occurs
  NSArray *sortedArray = [self.unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; 

            return sortedArray;
}
```

And yes, all the objects of the 'unsortedArray' has the property specified in the descriptor. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the `NSSortDescriptor`?

Answer (score 1):

My bad!

I've been calling this method from various parts of my project. And on one, I was passing a String instead of the descriptor.

This was causing the issue.